# download epub file programmatically ios

Tags: iphone, ios, download, asihttprequest, epub

in my app i need to download .epub file
I am using web-service like this :

```
{"categories":[{"cat_id":"10","cat_name":"\u10ec\u10d8\u10d2\u10dc\u10d4\u10d1\u10d8","cat_image":null,"cat_list":[{"sub_cat_name":"\u10df\u10d0\u10dc\u10e0\u10d8","Cat_Data":[{"prod_name":"https://www.readerwill.com/\u10ec\u10d8\u10d2\u10dc\u10d8\u10e1 \u10d0\u10d5\u10e2\u10dd\u10e0\u10d8 1.epub","prod_price":"4.9500","prod_image":"https://www.mysite.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/295x295/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/s/a/sample.jpg"},........
```

now i want to add "prod_url" so that i can download it using ASIHttprequest ,but product url is in .html format.

the problem is how can i download epub programmatically ??

thanks...

Answer (score 0):

did you try to use [request setDownloadDestinationPath:@"/Users/ben/Desktop/my_file.epub"]; and in request url you set your webservice?

Comment: Thanks Anton but what is my url for download epub file ?

Comment: i think this one https://www.readerwill.com/\u10ec\u10d8\u10d2\u10dc\u10d8\u10e1 \u10d0\u10d5\u10e2\u10dd\u10e0\u10d8